# Character limit on input text

Tags: angularjs, validation, input, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to my textbox to only allow numbers and also have a character limit on it.

Currently, I have the numbers working... Now I am having issues figuring out how to limit the characters.

Here is what I have...

JS:

```
app.directive('numbersonly', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            elm.on('keydown', function (event) {
                if (event.which == 64 || event.which == 16 && elm.val().length > 4) {
                    return false;
                } else if (event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) {
                    return true;
                } else if (event.which >= 96 && event.which <= 105) {
                    return true;
                } else if ([8, 13, 27, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(event.which) > -1 && elm.val().length > 4) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Markup:

```
<input type="text" id="txtEmpAge" data-ng-model="newemployee.Age" class="form-control" numbersonly required />
```

Answer (score 9):

In html input attribute length. we can use it in multiple forms:

Length, Minlength and maxlength

Try this

```
maxlength="5"
```

Comment: Can you simply change the attribute on the element you passed in your link function, if you don't want to handle it in HTML? Am I missing something, because I assume you have to put the limit you want on the isolated scope, which you will have to put in your HTML on the directive or do you want all the input to be the same length.

Comment: @Maccurt because i am using a similar directive for input number which doesn't allow maxlength and max doesn't seem to work that well

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and wrote a directive to figure it all out. Then I found a plug in called angular-dynamic-number and it worked for me right out the box. I would suggest you use that if it meets your need. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-dynamic-number

Comment: I don't want to have a plugin to do this

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use a plug in?